# Change the internal behaviour of a JVM (more precisely Dalvik)

Tags: android, random, jvm, dalvik

The question is maybe not that precise, but I didn't find the answer on the Internet and I would be interested to learn about it: as many JVM are open source, would it be possible to change their internal behaviour? For example, would it be possible to mock their random function (and set always 42 as Random number? :) ).

I would like to try to change this function in a Dalvik VM (I'm Android fan), recompile it and try to push it to my phone to see the effects on it.

Also, in this precise case, won't it create a security hole because classes like `SecureRandom` won't be able to work correctly?

Actually, I'm developer but I'm trying to go a bit deeper (because learning is always cool) but I got no precise idea of it. Is it at least possible what I'm figuring out or I totally misunderstood the whole workflow ?

Comment: You can do what you are asking. But, the dangers of changing it are only present in your version of the operating system that you have recompiled.  It's not like you are putting others in danger.  It would only work for someone else in that manner if they loaded your OS.

Comment: Yes, that was clear but do you think the security of my device would be affected by these kind of manipulations?

Comment: It's possible that you are putting yourself in danger of doing so, yes.  Changing a security feature could prove harmful to you and leave you exposed. Such as changing a secure number generator.  Even small modifications could open up holes that you might not think of.

Comment: And do you have an idea about how I could precisely accomplish this experience ? (Recompile libdvm and so on...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Dynamic Dalvik Instrumentation](https://github.com/crmulliner/ddi).  There is a link to the SummerCon presentation with slides and examples.